# How to create Mouse event on Rectangle[X] after create Rectangle[X]

Tags: c#, wpf, mouseevent

my code for crate rectangle :

```
     Rectangle[] myRectangle = new Rectangle[100];
     for(int i=1;i<=100;i++)
     {
          myRectangle[i] = new Rectangle();
          // another code for create myRectangle[i]
     }
```

When MouseEnter Rectangle[X] and I want to do something.What will i do?
Thank you.

Comment: First, your loop will raise an exception. There is no element 100, but you are trying to access it. Change the loop to start at 0 and run while < 100, or use foreach. As for the event, you should be able to hook to OnMouseEnter event. I haven't checked yet.

Comment: `myRectangle[i].MouseEnter += <your event handler method>`.

Comment: I use rectangle[i].RaiseEvent(new RoutedEventArgs(MouseEnterEvent)); to create MouseEnterEvent but i don't know where i can create corde for MouseEnter on rectangle[x] because my x value (1-100) has difference code when MouseEnter.

Comment: RaiseEvent raises the event. This is not what you want. @Clemens has the code above. If you do that in the loop, it will fire for all rectangles. You can then check the `sender` to determine which rectangle fired the event

Comment: I use code @Clemens i don't know to do use <your event handler method>.

Comment: Example : i want to MessageBox.Show(i.Tostring()) in <your event handler method> what i should do?

Comment: Press `Tab` twice in VS. The handler looks like this; `private void MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {}`. The `<your event handler method>` gets replaced with `MouseEnter`

Comment: @bixarrio I don't understand can you explain me.

Comment: i want to do  'MessageBox.Show(i.Tostring())' in '<your event handler method>' after i use 'myRectangle[i].MouseEnter += <your event handler method>'

Comment: Create a function with the above signature. `private void MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {}`. This is the event handler. Hook up this handler to the rectangles `myRectangle[i].MouseEnter += MouseEnter;`. Put your handling in the handler. You will have a slight problem though, because the event handler will not have the index of the rectangle, but the actual rectangle that was entered by the mouse. If you really need the index, you could add `myRectangle[i].Tag = i;`

Answer (score 0):

Putting this here;

```
Rectangle[] myRectangle = new Rectangle[100];
for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    myRectangle[i] = new Rectangle();
    myRectangle[i].Tag = i;
    myRectangle[i].MouseEnter += MouseEnter;
}
private void MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Rectangle rect = (Rectangle)sender;
    int idx = (int)rect.Tag;
    MessageBox.Show(idx.ToString());
}
```

Comment: I'd suggest to replace the first two lines of the handler method by `var rect = (Rectangle)sender;` because if the sender - for whatever reason -  would not be a Rectangle, you would correctly get an InvalidCastException instead of silently ignoring it.

Comment: @Clemens In this case I wanted to ignore the exception, but you are absolutely correct. I'll update the answer